# Embed image not showing on email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro to send some emails, but the embed images goes with a "x" to the recievers.

My email have: anex, body text and the embed images.

```
Option Explicit

Dim lsave As String


Sub Arquivoanex()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim oEmail As Object
Dim strBody As String

Dim line As String
Dim subject As String
Dim destine As String
Dim anex As String
Dim product As String
Dim unit As String
Dim retval As String
Dim anex_name As String
Dim validation As String
Dim signature As String

line = 3

product = "x"

Do While product <> ""

    Set oEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    product = Sheets("Send_Emails").Range("M" & line)
    unit = Sheets("Send_Emails").Range("N" & line)
    destine = Sheets("Send_Emails").Range("O" & line)
    subject = Sheets("Send_Emails").Range("P" & line)
    anex = Sheets("Send_Emails").Range("Q" & line)
    anex_name = Sheets("Send_Emails").Range("R" & line)
    validation = Sheets("Send_Emails").Range("L" & line)

    signature = "\\...\signature.png"

    Sheets("Send_Emails").Range("S1") = product

    retval = Dir(anex)

    If retval = anex_name Then

    Else
        GoTo next_anex
    End If

    If anex = "" Then
        GoTo next_anex
    End If

    Sheets("Send_Emails").Select
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    Select Case product

        Case Is = "X"
            Sheets("X").Select
            Range("K3") = unit
            ActiveSheet.Calculate

        Case Is = "Y"
            If validation = "Send" Then
                Sheets("Y").Select
                Range("K3") = unit
                ActiveSheet.Calculate
            Else: GoTo next_anex

            End If
    End Select

    On Error Resume Next

    Call lCriarImagem 'Creates the image and give the location

    strBody = Sheets("Send_Emails").Range("B9") & "<img src=""cid:TempExportChart.bmp""height=520 width=750>" & "<br/><br/>TKS! <br/><br/></body>"

    MailItem.Attachments.Add FName, 1, 0

    With oEmail

    .Display
    oEmail.From = "mail_from@mail"
    oEmail.To = "mail_to@mail"
    oEmail.subject = subject
    oEmail.Attachments.Add FName, 1, 0
    oEmail.AddAttachment anex
    oEmail.HTMLBody = strBody & .HTMLBody

    oEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    oEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "myserver.server"
    oEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/authenticate") = 1
    oEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update

    oEmail.Send

    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

next_anex:

    line = line + 1

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

It's posible to fix this problems using this code structure?

> Obs: This is the code after all the sugestions.
>
> I still facing the problems with the "X" on the email:https://ibb.co/0hX6Dvf ("The photo cannot be show. Maybe the file cam be moved, renamed or excluded. Verify if the destiny is in the correct location").

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the images as file attachments, set the "content-id" MIME header on these attachment MIME parts, and make suire teh HTML body refers to the image attachents by content id (e.g. `<img src="cid:my-xcontent-id">`).

Comment: I tried using this "<img src="cid:my-xcontent-id">", but I don't know how to set the header on the attachments.

Comment: Were you able to **add** the attachment?

Comment: Please show your code and the resulting MIME message.

Comment: I do not see your code setting the content-id header on the attachment.to "TempExportChart.bmp"

Comment: Could you please help me doing this? I don't now how to do that right.

Comment: Are you doing this using the Outlook Object Model or CDO?

Comment: I am doing using CDO. I tried using OOM, but don't worked well.

Comment: AddAttachment  call returns IBodyPart object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2007/aa581351(v%3Dexchg.80) ). You need to set the MIME header using BodyPart.Fields.Item - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2007/aa581142(v=exchg.80)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the image and hide it. The position 0 will add and hide it.

```
MailItem.Attachments.Add Fname, 1, 0
```

The `1` is the Outlook Constant `olByValue`.

Once you add the image then you have to use "cid:FILENAME.jpg" as shown below. For example:

```
With OutMail
    .To = tName   
    .Subject = "Hello world!"
    .Attachments.Add Fname, 1, 0
    .HTMLBody = "<img src=""cid:Claims.jpg""height=520 width=750>"
    .Display
End With
```

Also, you may set the attachment content ID explicitly:

```
Function SendasAttachment(fName As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachments

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olMsg = olApp.CreateItem(0) ' email
Set olAtt = olMsg.Attachments

Const PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001E"
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"

' attach file
olAtt.Add (fldName & fName)

Set l_Attach = olAtt.Add(fldName & fName)
Set oPA = l_Attach.PropertyAccessor
       oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG, "image/jpeg"
       oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "myident"
       oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN, True

olMsg.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B", True

olMsg.To = "test@somedomain.com"
msgHTMLBody = "<HTML>" & _
                   "<head>" & _
                   "</head>" & _
                   "<BODY>" & "Hi " & olMsg.To & ", <br /><br /> I have attached " & fName & " as you requested." & _
                   "<br /><img align=baseline border=1 hspace=0 src=cid:myident width='400'/>" & _
                   "</BODY></HTML>"
' send message
With olMsg
  .Subject = "Hello world!"
  .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
  .HTMLBody = msgHTMLBody
  .Save
  '.Display
  .Send
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Eugene, I tried using this code you sent, but I still facing the same error ("X").

Comment: I have just updated the post. Please see the code shown above.